# Equivalent in git for `darcs whatsnew --summarize`? it summarizes current changes per file

Tags: git, git-diff

I tried

```
git diff --summary
```

as stated in `git diff help`, but changes are not being summarized, `git diff` does output changes in 5 different files.

Is there another way?

Example of `darcs whatsnew --summarize` output:

```
M ./XMonad/Prompt.hs -1 +1
M ./XMonad/Prompt/Shell.hs -1 +1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`git diff --stat`

it gives a nice line-per-file list/graph showing lines added and removed.